# How to append the wifi data values obtained from airodump-ng to the same csv file every 15 seconds?

Tags: linux, csv, wifi

I'm currently working on a project in indoor positioning, for which I need to collect the wi-fi beacon frame(bssid,pwr,ssid) of all the nearby wi-fi in different positions and have the data file in the same csv file.
For that we are using airodump-ng which returns the wi-fi data values in csv.

```
sudo airodump-ng Output --output-format csv wlp2s0
```

For each position I'm getting a new csv file. Can somebody suggest me a way so that the data file gets updated every 15 seconds with the new values so that I can get all the data values in the same csv file.

Comment: Does airodump-ng write a file (if so what name) or to stdout? Can you give a snippet of the file to see if/what the header looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of airodump-ng has the --write-interval option it will probably just do the right thing, i.e:

```
sudo airodump-ng --output-format csv --write $(data --iso=s) --write-interval 15 wlp2s0
```

Otherwise my advise would be to write each output to a separate file (i.e. $(date --iso=s).csv), then post-process it to combine the data.  This ensures you don't lose data if you have a defect in your post-process process:

```
head -1 $(find -name \*.csv | head -1) > result.csv
find -name \*.csv | xargs cat | grep -v 'header match' >> result.csv
```